# Unexpected redirect after login with JAAS and Vaadin Push

Tags: java, vaadin7, jboss6.x, jaas, atmosphere

I am using Vaadin Push in one of my applications that relies on JAAS login. There seems to be a situation where the two frameworks collide.

I have configured the security constraints like this:

```
<!-- This is the exclusion I talk about below -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ecomsupportform</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/PUSH</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
<!-- This is the exclusion I talk about below -->

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ecomsupportform</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name> 
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <description>any</description>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

When I refresh the page after my session times out, the login page shows up. But then Vaadin seems to want to close the Push-Session by sending a close request to the server via Atmosphere, which JBoss notices and prevents because I'm not logged in yet. Although I don't know what happened to the Push-Session, when I know log in, JBoss redirects me to the `.../PUSH`-URL which Vaadin sent just before. A blank screen appears.

I tried to maybe prevent JBoss from catching the `PUSH`-Request by excluding it from authentication. Now when Vaadin sends its close-request, the browser shows a 500 in the network-tab (instead of 401 HTTP Response Code) and when I log in, the same thing happens.

I have also tried setting Push to MANUAL mode, or using the many different transport mechanisms.

PS: In case it helps. When I land on the login page and reload it before logging in, everything works fine.

Is there any way to prevent JBoss from redirecting like this after login? Or can I fix this otherwise?